# Recursion Factorial terminating due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, recursion, factorial

I am trying to learn recursion and I am attempting to do factorial's via recursion instead of loops, but my program is causing "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

```
class RecursionFactorial
{
    public static int n;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to work out the factorial");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        bool test = int.TryParse(input, out n);
        fact(n);

    }
    public static int fact(int y)
    {
        int count = n;
        if (y <= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(y);
        }
        else
        {
            count = (count * y);
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            fact(y - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and this is **definitely** the code that produces that error? I don't see any recursion....

Comment: @spender sorry i left out a line of code in the method to do the recursion i'll edit now

Comment: Still not right code. You don't return a value. Won't compile.

Comment: Make very sure you copy paste the _actual_ code that causes the problem. Also, what input?

Comment: Remember, factorial(y) = y * factorial(y-1). The `count` variable should be removed.

Comment: thanks guys i'm a new programmer i did the return stuff and edited my calculation and its working , much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In any **Recursion** you must have a **case**,where your **recursion is ended**.So you must enter `return` keyword to your function.

```
public static int fact(int y)
{
    if (y <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return y * fact(y - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed with this code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n;
        string input;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to work out the factorial");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        bool test = int.TryParse(input, out n);

        int factorial = fact(n);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} factorial is {1}", n, factorial);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    public static int fact(int y)
    {
        if (y <= 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return y * fact(y - 1);
        }
```